# Can I create an instance of a class using a designated name?

Tags: ruby, class, instance

I have already wrote a class in ruby, call it *Foo*. Now I want to create some instance of it. However, I want to use the value stored in a variable as the name of the instance.

For example, the value of a variable *bar* is "ABC". Now I want to make the name of the new instance "ABC" as the statement *ABC = Foo.new*

Can I realize this? If it is possible, please tell me how. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, you should also not be afraid to use eval(), as long as you feed it only data constructed by you, the programmer, without unsafe external influence. In this case,

```
cocos = "ABC"
class_sym = :Foo
eval "#{cocos} = #{class_sym}.new"
```

Eval has bad reputation in many languages, but in Ruby, its quite comfortable and basically as fast as static code.

Comment: I know it does. #eval is a hammer, especially before you learn those weaker, and thus safer ways, such as in this case self.class.const_set(:ABC, self.class.const_get(:Foo).new) :)))

Answer (score 1):

as a *local* variable, no, but you can use [instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) and friends to name the created objects as instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `const_set` if you are really working with constants:

```
constant = 'ABC'
Object.const_set constant.to_sym, Foo.new
```